# Український відповідник до слова "блог"

Tags: відповідник

Популярне слово [блог](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3) означає:

> Веб-сайт, головний зміст якого — записи, зображення чи мультимедіа, що
>   регулярно додаються. Для блоґів характерні короткі записи тимчасової
>   значущості.

І походить від англ. blog, від web log — "мережевий журнал чи щоденник подій". Можемо часто зустріти це слово в мережі (наприклад, [блог професора Пономарева](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/topics/ponomariv)), тому цікавить чи є якийсь український відповідник до цього слова. На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/blog) найпопулярнішим варіантом є "денник". Також бачимо це слово в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/dennyk), де вказується що це синонім до слова "щоденник", однак слід зауважити, що блог не обов'язково ведеться кожного дня (записи можуть виходити як і кожного тижня, так і раз у два тижні, або ж декілька разів на день). Є там і варіант "дописник", який також не буде дуже влучним, коли ми захочемо замінити такі похідні слова від "блог" як "блогосфера", "блогер", "відеоблогер" тощо, адже слово "допис" має значення:

> Стаття, повідомлення про що-небудь, написані для газети, журналу і т.
>   ін. кореспондентом або читачем

Тобто це може бути тільки щось написане, тому це "дописник" не дуже підійде як відповідник. З усіх інших варіантів, цікавим  і, на мою думку, найбільш влучним виявивилось слово "мережевик" ("мережевик", "відеомережевик" (проте як бути у цьмоу випадку зі словами "блогер" та "блогосфера" не знаю)), однак не впевнений, чи це слово не буде суперечити українському словотвору.

Comment: Не треба перекладати слово "блог", це вже самостійний термін, лаконічний і всім зрозумілий. Це слово прийшло в нашу мову одразу із його смислом. Як компьютеру, принтеру або ноутбуку йому переклад не потрібен.

Answer (score -1):

Зазначу, що несприйняття *денник* тут дещо даремне:

> *блоґ не обов’язково веде ся щодня*

Теж зауважу, що тут *денник*, а не ***що**денник*. Можна взяти ще показовий приклад: [*журнал*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0) французькою означає ***що**денник*. Тобто лиш, наприклад, *шкільний журнал* є найближчим за першозначінням, однак тут прижило ся і для тих видань, котрі випускають ся *не **що**дня*.

Про похоџення [*blog*](//etymonline.com/word/blog): схоже є злиттям *we**b*** та [*log*](//etymonline.com/word/log). Першоџерело далеке від тутешнього значіння і складне для визначення, тому базуватимемося попереднім словоџерелом, а саме [*log-book*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logbook), котре має значіння ***the daily** record of a ship's speed, progress, etc.* Тобто тим, чим зараз теж би скоріш назвали ***що**денником*, порівняйте з тямками иншими мовами: мск. [*судовой журнал*](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB), п. [*dziennik okrętowy*](//pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dziennik_okr%C4%99towy), блґ. [*корабен дневник*](//bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)…

Зрозуміло, що значінням *щоденник* не ріжнить ся від *денник*, але тут можна цього втілити. Також створювати складні слова не складно: *денникар*, *видиводенник*, *денннико[зосяг](https://ia902801.us.archive.org/8/items/shtepa1977/shtepa1977.PDF)*…

---

Ще зауважу, що СУМ-11 писав ся за совітські часи, наприклад книга з буквою **д** випустила ся аж-но в 1971 році. А ось в наступній книзі, роком пізнїше, маємо наступне:

> ЗАПИС, у, чол.
>
> 2. Те, що становить письмовий виклад або результат записування чого-небудь на *плівці*, *пластинці*.

Хоч тоді це виглядало як щось сучасне, то для сьогоднішнього дня… чуттєво застарілим. А наразі *видивозапис* є звичним словом.

Але навіть для *блоґ* теж не підходить, не тому що складно утворювати чи лиш для *паперу*, а розбіг значінням словами *стаття*, *повідомлення*. Тобто це однозначно не *блоґ*, котре є *збіркою* всього цього, але при цьому є частиною *блоґ*. В такому разі *дописник* може бути влучним, коли *блоґ* ведуть декілька осіб, що вже є чимось звичним на сьогоднішний день — це перважно для блоґу компаній.

---

Слова *мережевик* і подальші теж не підходять, бо корінь слова тут є [*мережа*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0), що вже є далеко не *блоґ*. Тобто *мережевик*, за лоґікою, буде людина, котра відповідає за мережу, причому в фізічному стані і не обовʼязково саме *інтернету*, тобто є наприклад ще *телефона мережа*. Моя догадка виявила ся і є вірною, коли набрати *мережевик* в [пошуку](//google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off) — там згадують ся саме ті люди, котрі мають справи з *мережею*, а не з *блоґом*.

Слїд також зазначити, що *мережа*, або точнїше *інтернет*, є лиш засобом, а не основою *лоґу*, тобто *лоґ* [можна вести](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog) і не мережею, а як по старинці, щось схоже на „через пластівці“: з популярного наразі таке є через *авдіво*, що виходить як майже *радіво*, але не зовсїм *наживо*.

Коли важливо звернути увагу який саме *log*, то можна повторювати за анґлійцями. Тобто, коли брати за основу *денник*, то легко матимемо відповідні *м-денник* чи *е-денник*, *в-денник*, *а-денник*…

Comment: Саме тому мені і сподобався варіант "мережевик", бо ж як було зазначено саме слово "блог" можна дослівно перекласти як "мережевий журнал", а от у словах "денник" та "дописник" немає ніякого натяку на те, що записи ведуться в мережі.

Comment: Що за *авдіво*? Що за „через пластівці“?

Comment: Хіба ваше посилання доводить, що можна вести і не мережею. Що таке вести *мережею*? Типу мережею агентів, які щось роблять?

Comment: @Yola audio, [платівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Грамофонна_платівка). Так, тобто не лише через _веб-блоґ_. Останнім часом набувајуть силу канали-блоґи. _Вести мережею_, це означає _в мережі_, наче все зрозуміло, јак і _вести автівкоју_, ньі?

Comment: ні, везти автівкою по автобану, і вести друкуванням і ще чимось *в мережі*.

Comment: А ці канали вони не в мережі? Як воше посилання на англійську вікі довоидить, що можна вести не в мережі?

Comment: Так що таке *авдіво*? Не загалом, а конкретно в вашому дописі? що через нього ведуть блог.

Comment: Я читаю вас уважно, від нині всі ваші пости, з подібним підбором слів буду мінусувати

Comment: @follower, прошу утриматися від таких оцінок чужих коментарів як «срач». Що для одного несуттєво (і навіть заважає), то для іншого може бути найважливішим.